# WindowsBuilder: How to draw a component when press a button?

Tags: java, swing, layout, draw, paintcomponent

I wish to draw a rectangle when a button is pressed but it doesn't seem to work.
here is my code:

```
package draw.rect;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

public class DR extends JFrame {

    private JPanel contentPane;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    DR frame = new DR();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the frame.
     */
    public DR() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 458, 312);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        setContentPane(contentPane);
        contentPane.setLayout(null);

        JButton btnDrawRrect = new JButton("Draw Rrect");
        btnDrawRrect.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                System.out.print("hello");
                RectangleComponent r2 = new RectangleComponent();
                contentPane.add(r2);
                r2.revalidate();
                contentPane.revalidate();
            }
        });
        btnDrawRrect.setBounds(10, 11, 89, 23);
        contentPane.add(btnDrawRrect);    
    }
}

package draw.rect;

import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Rectangle;

import javax.swing.JComponent;

public class RectangleComponent extends JComponent {

      Rectangle rect;

      public RectangleComponent()
      {
        rect  = new Rectangle(50, 50, 120, 130);
      }

      public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
      {
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2.draw(rect);
      } 
}
```

The problem is that when the action event listener is called, the JComponent is properly constructed but it was not added to the frame.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5):

You're using a null layout, and when doing so you are fully responsible for setting the size and position of any components added to the null layout using container. You are ignoring this responsibility and are not giving your added JComponent a size or position, and so while it is being added to the container, it cannot be seen since its size is 0. To prove this to yourself, add a System.out.println() that prints out if the added component is visible and what its bounds are and you'll see for yourself. Your second issue is that you are not calling `repaint()` after adding the component, though this isn't always necessary and isn't the reason for your current problem. A quick fix is to set the bounds of the newly added component, but I don't recommend that you do this. Instead I recommend:

- I strongly urge you not to use null layouts as they make your code inflexible and *very* difficult to maintain and upgrade.
- Read up on in the tutorials and use the layout managers.
- After removing or adding components from a container, call `revalidate()` and then `repaint()` on the container.

Comment: I am actually using WindowsBuilder Pro to construct my JFrame so that's why the layout is set to null. Is that the problem why the rectangle was not drawn?

Comment: @user2109278: again, the rectangle is not shown because the component that holds it has a size of 0,0. Note that WindowsBuilderPro is not forcing you to use a null layout, and you can still use all the layout managers with this tool, although I recommend that until you understand Swing well, you not use a code-generating library.